# SQL query to extract data from three tables based on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Imagine three data tables A, B and C. A and B share a common variable ID1. B and C share a common variable ID2. Write a pseudo query to get this result: select everything from Table B, with matching records in both Table A and B, but not in Table C.

My version of the answer is below (but I am not sure if it's correct):

```
Select *
From table_b
Left Join table_a
On table_b.ID1 = table_a.ID1
Where table_b.ID2 NOT IN table_c.ID2
```

I am very skeptical about if the Where condition would work for the given condition? Please give your opinion on my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *
From table_b
Left Join table_a On table_b.ID1 = table_a.ID1
Where not exists (select * from table_c where table_c.ID2 = table_b.ID2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to IngoB's solution but slightly more readable (IMHO)

```
SELECT *
FROM table_b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_a USING (id1)
WHERE id2 NOT IN (SELECT id2 FROM table_c)
```

Comment: It depends on the data and database platform being used, but the NOT EXISTS method can perform better than NOT IN. For SQL Server, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: Which solution is faster - if there is a difference at all - largely depends on the distribution of the data and the indexing of both tables. The last time I looked at this on Oracle the optimizer always came up with the same execution plan for both variants.

Comment: *Important:* My solution is only equivalent to IngoB's if there are no NULL values in TABLE_C.ID2. I assumed it was a PK column and therefore there would not be NULL values but if this is not the case Ingo's solution is the correct one.